# How to change a bot's App ID?

Tags: botframework

I've created 3 bots (prod, stg and dev versions) with the bot framework. I must have accidentally deleted the prod Msft app awhile back. I can't seem to create a new app to replace the old defunct one associated with the prod bot. Is there a way to do this? I'd rather avoid deleting and recreating the app and reconfiguring associated channels. Seems odd this isn't possible. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get something. Was the Prod BOT deleted or the PROD Website in Azure deleted?

Comment: The production bot's Microsoft App ID/Password was deleted. I'm not using Azure. My production bot is still present but references an old app that no longer exists. I can't change it to associate with a new App ID/password.

Comment: I think you will have to create a new bot in the BotFramework dev portal and update the settings in your bot...

Answer (score 0):

Ezequiel is right; unfortunately you can't currently change the MSA App ID of your bot.  I'll talk to the team to see if there's any convenient workaround we can apply.